# Error installing Git-Flow in bash for GitHub for Windows

Tags: git, github, git-flow, github-for-windows

I'm fairly new to Git, and started by using GitHub for Windows.
Now I've learned how to open a Git bash....and want to install Git Flow into it.

I'm trying to follow the steps here:-
https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Windows

During the installation, when I try to run the msysgit-install script using my path for the PortableGit folder, the script fails saying:-

```
contrib/msysgit-install.cmd: line 1: @echo: command not found
contrib/msysgit-install.cmd: line 2: setlocal: command not found
```

etc...

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is my bash not properly setup?

I'm accessing the bash by right clicking on the project in GitHub for Windows, and selecting 'open a shell here'.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `msysgit-install.cmd` script is a windows batch file, don't run it from bash run it from windows command prompt (or double click it from the file browser, but I am not sure if that will work for a `.cmd` file...)

Also, try using Cygwin instead.  It is much simpler.

Comment: That seemed to work for the installation steps....but now running git flow help in bash is getting an error 'libiconv2.dll is missing'.
I guess the installation instructions aren't complete.
I might give Cygwin a go, as you said.

Comment: @SeanHolmesby libiconv2.dll is used to translate from one encoding such as Latin-1 to another like UTF-8

Comment: @SeanHolmesby The installation instuction have been updated since to include the libiconv dependancy.

Comment: @Grhm Thanks for that. Could you possibly update the 'Github for Windows' section as well? I noticed the libiconv dependency is only mentioned in the 'MSysGit' section. Also, maybe you could add that msysgit-install.cmd needs to be run from a normal command prompt, not just the git bash (as mentioned by @randomusername)? The installation now works perfectly. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 5):

- Download [here util-linux](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/util-linux-ng.htm) binaries and dependencies files
- Uncompress those files (util-linux-ng--bin.zip and util-linux-ng--dep.zip)
- Copy `util-linux-ng-<version>-bin\bin\getopt.exe` file into `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`
- Copy `util-linux-ng-<version>-dep\bin\libintl3.dll` and `util-linux-ng-<version>-dep\bin\libiconv2.dll` files into `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`
- Open Git Bash console and clone Git Flow repository: `git clone git://github.com/nvie/gitflow.git`
- Go to gitflow directory: `cd gitflow`
- Execute command: `git submodule`
- Execute command: `git submodule init`
- Execute command: `git submodule update`
- Open `Windows console` and go to `contrib` directory from `gitflow` directory where you cloned the repository: `cd C:\... ...\gitflow\contrib\`
- Execute the command to install git flow: `msysgit-install.cmd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git"`

Comment: I kept missing a crucial point - passing the git path to msysgit-install.cmd and none of the blogs/forums helped - yours did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use Chocolatey and install the 4 packages here: [Chocolatey Git-Flow related packages](https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=git-flow).

Make sure you add your Git\bin install directory to the Path in Environment Variables.

Make sure to restart cmd.exe and run `git flow help` to ensure it works.